# Problemas con un repeater en wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Quería saber como puedo seperar un poco mas la linea "|" entre teléfono y teléfono  osea darle mas aire, probé darle margin-left pero no queda bien estilisticamente.[image]

```html
     <ul class="atencion">
                     <?php if(have_rows('telefonos_header',4)):
                       $raya = " | ";
                      
                     ?> 

                       <?php         
                           while(have_rows('telefonos_header',4)): 
                           the_row();
                       ?>
                       <li>  
                        <i class="icon-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        <strong><?php the_sub_field('telefono_del_lugar',4); ?></strong>
                        <a href="tel:<?php the_sub_field('numero_visible',4); ?>" title="Telefeno Camconnection"><?php the_sub_field('numero_visible',4); ?></a><?php echo $raya; ?>  
                       </li>
                     <?php
                         $raya = ""; 
                         endwhile; ?>
                       
                     <?php endif; ?>      
     </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay dos problemas en el HTML que genera tu código:

- El `|` queda ubicado dentro de un `<ul>` pero no en un `<li>`, lo que es semánticamente incorrecto, y hace difícil modificar el estilo (por eso no te da resultados el margin-left).
- El `|` lo estás usando solamente como elemento decorativo. La "buena práctica" es resolver estos asuntos cosméticos usando CSS.

Te propongo esta solución, que puedes implementar adaptando el CSS a tu página, y quitando el "|" del código PHP que publicaste.

```css
body { background:#444; color: #FFF; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; }
ul { list-style:none; padding-left: 0; }
li { display: inline-block; border-right: 1px solid #FFF; padding: 0 1em; }
li:last-child { border-right: 0; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Tel (MEX): 52 (55) 1253 7363</li>
  <li>Tel (ARG): 54 (11) 5263 3254</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Entonces vos decís que por css puedo mejorar esos cambios?

Comment: Digo que para lo que necesitas (darle más aire al separador "|") te sirve CSS. Ejecuta el snippet de código que puse y ve el resultado. Modifícalo para adaptarlo a tu página.